# Rails - routing (id & action order in URL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(I am learning Rails and MVC development)

How does the rule 
`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`
match this URL ?

```
http://localhost:3000/people/1/edit
```

'id' (1) appears before 'action' (edit), so it should Not match , right ?

Comment: What makes you think it's this rule that matches this url?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - It is the only rule that is there in config/routes.rb

Comment: Probably not. Post the whole routes.rb here. I'm sure we'll find a `resources :people` there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Yes, there is a "resources :people" in the file

Comment: That's what matches this url

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - thanks.. I will read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That URL does not match that route.

That route is a fallback URL that should not be used in your applications. It exists as a suggestion in your routes file for legacy applications only.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use like that. Use

```
:resources people
```